# error with archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, archive

I haven't experience with xcode and I'm trying to publish my first app. I created the app id and the distribution profile and set up the bundle identifier as the same as the distribution profile. I have also changed the code sign identity to iPhone Distribution, but when i click archive or run it say "build failed" and this is the error:

```
arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: /Users/myname/Desktop/iLibe/iOrario liceo bellinzonaBLACK/iLiBe: No such file or directory
arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: warning: '-x objective-c-header' after last input file has no effect
arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
 Command/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using `clang` instead of `llvm-gcc`?  Anyway did you read the error message?  What is that missing file all about?